# Caused by: GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, retrofit2

Here, I have two Activities, *Activity_a* with **some_button** and an Activity_B. When **some_button** is clicked on *Activity_a*, *Activity_b* will appear. In *Activity_b*, I tried to fetch JSON_OBJECT using ***[retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)*** and show the data in recyclerview.

For the first time everything goes well, after clicking some_button in Activity_a , Activity_b appears with list of data in recyclerView. *But If I press back from Activity_B and again tried to click some_button of Activity_a again and the screen remains black and shows the following error.*

***Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: 
Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.***
[image]

This wired issue lost my whole days, Please help me out if anyone had faced the same issue earlier or have any idea about it.

**Activity_A.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.fab) {

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, Activity_B.class);
        startActivity(activityIntent);


    }
}
```

**Activity_B.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
    toolbarAndViewInitialization();


    /** Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    GetMessageDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetMessageDataService.class);

    /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
    Call<MessageList> call = service.getMessageData();

    /**Log the URL called*/
    Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

    materialDialog.show();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MessageList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MessageList> call, Response<MessageList> response) {
            ArrayList<Message> noticeList = response.body().getMessageArrayList();
            initDataToRecyclerView(noticeList);
            materialDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MessageList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Error message: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            materialDialog.hide();
        }
    });

}
```

**RetrofitInstance.java**

```
public class RetrofitInstance {

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL2 = "https://someurl.com/";

/**
 * Create an instance of Retrofit object
 */
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApisUtils.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance2() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL2)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!!**

In my case this problem arises due to silly mistake in **for loop**. Even after pressing back button the *for-loop continuous to put data in array_list* and increase in memory buffer size.